# Extending selections based on value of selected features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, data, geoprocessing, qgis-processing

I have a layer with lots of features. Every feature has the `data` attribute. I could select some features by `Select by location` based on other layer(s) or just by free hand (yellow points as example).

[image]

The task is to select all other features with the same `data` attribute.

[image]

I am working in QGIS 2.18.10

I am seeing the solution by creating a new layer, than looping for the features for selecting ones with the same value in the raw layer. However, I need to process large datasets, so this solution looks unefficient.

Comment: If I understand well, starting from a selection manually made by you, you want to select all the features (in the same layer) storing the same values in the "data" field and then creating a new layer with all these features. Am I right?

Comment: yes, you are correct. The only thing is creating new layer is definitely not obligatory

Comment: Please, see my solution and let me know if it works (I can edit my answer if you need to save the selected features in a new layer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may run this code from the Python Console:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() # Load the layer as you want
field_name = 'data' # Set the field name of interest

values = []
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    tmp_value = feat[field_name]
    if tmp_value not in values:
        values.append(str(tmp_value)) # You may remove 'str' from this line if your field of interest already stores strings

strings = []
for val in values:
    if val != values[-1]:
        string = field_name + ' = ' + val + ' or '
        strings.append(string)
    else:
        last_string = field_name + ' = ' + val
        strings.append(last_string)
query = ''.join(strings)

request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
request.setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setFilterExpression(query)

selection = layer.getFeatures(request)
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

Starting from the features initially selected, it will select all the other features having the same values stored in the `"data"` field.

Then, it should run very fast because the feature request doesn't require geometries (see [here](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#aab0dc2dca2b882316c3bb3668dbf4667)).

Comment: perfect! An elegant solution. I have just added apostrophe symbol while creating query, to create < "data" = 'somevalue' or ...  >, cause my data field is string type

Comment: @MykolaKozyr, which line? Within the code, `val` is already a string.

Comment: `string = field_name + ' = ' + val + ' or '` to `string = field_name + " = '" + val + "' or "`. The same in `else` block

Comment: @MykolaKozyr Thanks for pointing it! I'm glad you found a working solution for you.